# How to stop feeling bad when you are leaving a company you like for a new job?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, job-change

I have been working in my current company for 2 years and I joined them right after my college . I thoroughly enjoyed my work, especially colleagues and the responsibility ( right from day 1, I had huge responsibility which I liked) that I had during those 2 years. There is always that extra tension to meet deadlines.

The company has a very weird structure. 80% of the development has less than 2 years experience and the rest have more than 6 years experience ( not in the company but overall professional experience ). The problem is I have been working on the salary that I signed up for initially. Less salary + feeling of being stagnant after 2 years + lack of guidance ( like someone with 4 years experience. The other people are unreachable, physically as well as intellectually) prompted me to look for other jobs and I got into this exciting opportunity and also pays me at least twice of what I earn right now.

So, now I want to quit and move on, and when I said this to my colleagues ( and also close friends with same experience level ), they started feeling bad and at least 6 ( that is 40% of the development force. There are so many days when we spent days at the office cracking at issues together, just out of interest and no extra salary) told me they would quit the job if I quit.

Now I feel bad. I genuinely like the company since they were my first job, had the chance to learn so many technologies, had nice colleagues and more than that I had huge responsibility right from day 1. Now I fear me quitting for another job would cause an exodus in the company. I don't know how to handle this situation. How to handle this situation?

Comment: Looking at my relatively young age, I've done a lot of jobs. Where ever I've been, I've met nice coworker I'm sad not to have around anymore. However, a new job is a new opportunity and new nice coworker. You are not responsibility to keep the company running, also you are not capable of doing this. If your quit would mean exitus for the company, the company is ill and going to die anyway. If it's really that bad, leave now before you're into the state of working for a dying company which is really bad.

Comment: We can't tell you to stay or go. That's too much responsibility for you to give away to the Internet. But you should ask yourself if you are willing to stay if they don't pay you more than what you started at, if they don't coach you at all, or provide feedback on your performance. Do you like the work and your colleagues enough that those things are tolerable?

Comment: *told me they would quit the job if I quit* That is not your responsibility. And I doubt that they actually will do so, all 6.

Comment: *If your quit would mean exitus for the company, the company is ill and going to die anyway. If it's really that bad, leave now before you're into the state of working for a dying company which is really bad.* +1 for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main thing you need to keep in mind is that your career is *your* career.  While you may feel loyalty towards a company, you need to ensure that a role is fulfilling and that you are remunerated appropriately.  Also remember that if the organisation needed to cut costs, they would not hesitate to reduce staffing levels.  They are in business to turn a profit, not to provide a job for you.

Loyalty to a company is admirable, but first and foremost you need to look after you *own* career path.

Answer (score 4):

> Now I fear me quitting for another job would cause an exodus in the
>   company. I don't know how to handle this situation. How to handle this
>   situation?

Leaving a good job is always awkward, particularly leaving your first job. The first time for many things is the hardest - it almost always gets easier as you go on in your career.

You were likely thrilled when you landed this job. You were excited that they chose you. You made many friends. You grew professionally. And now you are leaving them behind.

But new experiences await - a new job, new friends, new chances to grow.

While it feels like things may fall apart in your prior company, that almost never happens. Although you likely have a great network there, a mass-exodus is seldom triggered by one individual's exit when that individual has only been there for two years.

If a group of folks leave, you can be comforted that it almost certainly won't be because you left. Sure, whenever anyone leaves others think through and reassess their situation. But if they leave, it's because they saw something lacking themselves, or have found something far more tempting on their own.

And good companies can absorb people leaving - it's just part of the normal ebb and flow of business. They will carry on. And perhaps your leaving will open up opportunities for others.

When you leave, say goodbye to your coworkers and promise to stay in touch with your personal network. But try to put most of your energies into you new job, you new network, your new friends. Look forward, and not so much backward, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Normally people "mass-exodus" when the person left on grounds of being terminated due to a new rule or circumstances. At my prior employer, we had one such case where a person was fired then several others quit too. The funny thing is it barely impacted any business and the company wasn't hurt at all. Most companies know people will quit and leave and they also know they can replace that job relatively easily and/or make someone else take over that job.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy - I was really good friends with my colleagues at my last place (in fact, we're still good friends, and regularly meet up), and I felt bad about leaving them, especially as how there was another developer leaving at the same time. This equated to a 40% reduction in their development team.

But, you have to be happy and satisfied in your own work before you worry about anyone else - and as you start your question with a list of the things you were unhappy about, you have to as yourself, would it really be any better if you carried on.

You know what happened to my friends at the last place - nothing much. They had to pick up a few loose ends, but then they were working on new projects and work, and I doubt that, in the greater scheme of things, I was missed all that much (although, it is ego-stroking to think they really needed me).

I hate to deflate you with this, but if your quitting will really cause such an exodus from your current employer, then there are probably a lot of other issues and your leaving is just a tipping point rather than a catalyst.

So - how to not feel bad? Everyone moves on at some point - gone are the days where you start a job at 16 and retire from that same job (or even from the same company) at 65. And remember what you don't like about the job and are seeking to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I recently quit from my first job out of college. I been there nearly a decade. I do miss the place and sometimes feel a bit of "emptiness" when I think back on it. I miss the people and the place a little. Then I think about why I quit there. I think about the things I do dislike and realize I made a wise choice.

I think when you depart, you sort of only remember the good things. That's natural to do. I remember a lot of good things about my previous employer. But then I remember the bad things that made me want to leave and I know I made a wise choice for the better.

I recall a research done. I looked up information like you did on quitting and I recall reading a research that some folks talk really, really bad about their employer and quit on those grounds. Then shortly after they realize they made a terrible mistake and the last job was actually really good. I think what these research fail to see is that people quit a job to a new job without researching the new job. They just jumped on the chance for a new job since they were angry with their current employer. I would say so long as you don't do that, you should be okay. The feeling generally goes away after a few months or so, at least for me.