# Should I take an offer that solves my problem, but giving my coworkers more burden?

Tags: ethics, resignation, quitting, unprofessional-behavior, burnout

I'm a Java web developer working for more than 3 years. I developed web apps but never did operations. Meanwhile, employees are getting out one by one, and an operation work came to me; Legacy servers that ridiculously hard-coded with ASP.

While I never did ASP, I know that I can deal with it if I learn for a time. But just imagining I'm doing that is driving me crazy. I just don't want to do it. And doing that will certainly affect my current development works. So I told my thinking to my manager directly. His response was like this:

- It's hard to solve the problem since there are no other appropriate employees.
- I can offer you one of these:

  1. Take the ops works. I'll take care of your development schedule.
  2. You do dev and ops what you developed. But someone else(who is already taking another ops) has to do the ops that you are not taking.

My co-worker will take the burden if I'm being selfish(taking 2nd offer or quitting). I feel sorry for him, but I'm already burned-out with the stress. Should I suppress my unprofessional behavior and do what I got?

Comment: If you're burning out, it's not unprofessional to quit. Just do it. Your coworkers will need to negotiate for more help, less work, or will have to quit themselves. You're not responsible for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop feeling bad when you are leaving a company you like for a new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/how-to-stop-feeling-bad-when-you-are-leaving-a-company-you-like-for-a-new-job)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everyone's first responsibility is to do what is best for them. If moving on is the best thing for you, do it. At the end of the day, your work colleague isn't going to pay your mortgage or feed you or your kids.

Comment: This. Plus, the colleague has the same option available: They can refuse to do the work, too.

Answer (score 4):

In your question there is a reason why you shouldn't feel guilty or hesitate.

> •It's hard to solve the problem since there are no other appropriate employees.

It's company responsibility to assure smooth work and specialised employees for specialised tasks. If they don't have them it means they don't care about work or employees or the company itself is bad so employees don't want to work there.
Because you mention that people are getting out I would assume it's company fault and you shouldn't take their responsibility for assuring the company is working.
If they don't care you shouldn't. Your co-worker may soon follow your steps and leave the company.
If you stay you will be unhappy, your work will be badly done (because you will just want to get it done not done right) and it will benefit no-one (apart from management who will have scape-goat to blame).